# Returning false from onsubmit function doesn't prevent form from submitting

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

After I submit the form, the form will ignore the `onsubmit` whether the return is `true` or `false`, the form will directly go to form action.

I want to validate the input, if it is null it will remain on the same page and pop up an alert.

This is my JavaScript

```
<script>
    function validLogin() {
        if (document.login.username.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter Login Name.");
            document.loginform.userName.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (document.login.password.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter password.");
            document.userform.password.focus();
            return false;
        }
        alert("Welcome User");
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

This is my form

```
<form action="Login" method="post" name="login" onsubmit="return validLogin();">
```

Comment: try removing the action

Comment: action will be needed if all the values are validated

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo. The HTML says `name="login"` and while the JavaScript says `document.login.username.value` it also says `document.loginform.userName.focus();` which will throw an exception (because you changed the name of the form and input!), so the code never reaches `return false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The userName field is miscased in the code

```
<script>
    function validLogin() {
        if (document.login.username.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter Login Name.");
            document.login.username.focus();//Here
            return false;
        }
        if (document.login.password.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter password.");
            document.login.password.focus();
            return false;
        }
        alert("Welcome User");
        return true;
    }
</script>
```